# How to turn off Vim relativenumber setting?

Tags: vim

Today I have discovered vim's `relativenumber` option. I really would like to use it, but sometimes I need to swap between relative numbering and classic one.

[image]

I have tried to turn it off with `:set relativenumber=off` option (which returns me error attached above) and using `:set number` again but none of those works.

Comment: [Relevant link](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc)

Comment: With [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) you could use `cor` ("change option 'relativenumber'") to toggle `relativenumber`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To turn on relative line numbering use this:

```
:set rnu
```

To turn it off use this:

```
:set nornu
```

By the way, if you had Googled around for your question, you would have found [this great post](http://dlo.me/archives/2010/05/20/vim-with-relative-line-numbers/) which discusses things in more detail.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have vim 7.2 on redhat and it does not support `set rnu` . Is the command the same on all distros?

Answer (score 23):

To turn on whatever option in vim:

```
:set <option>
```

To turn off whatever option in Vim:

```
:set no<option>
```

To toggle an option on/off:

```
:set <option>!
```

To check if an option is on or off:

```
:set <option>?
```

To set an option back to its default:

```
:set <option>&
```

Comment: I did know about the last three options. Good to know now!

Answer (score 5):

I just use this toggle switch in my vimrc file.

```
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&rnu == 1)
    set nornu
  else
    set rnu
  endif
endfunc

nnoremap <C-l> :call NumberToggle()<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Relative Numbering is not turned on by default in vim, which means that you are probably turning it on through your `~/.vimrc` file or one of your plugins.  Look for `set relativenumber` or `set rnu`.

To turn it off for the current vim session you would simply run `set norelativenumber` or `set nornu` for short.  This is a normal vim pattern for turning on and off settings like this.  For example, spell check is `set spell` to activate and `set nospell` to deactivate.

To find this information and more on relative numbering, I recommend that you look in the vim help docs.  For this case, while in vim run `:h relativenumber`

Answer (score 2):

You actually have hybrid mode on (the line number your cursor is on is labelled as the absolute line number, not `0`). In this case, both `nu` and `rnu` are on. You'll need to remove both to remove line numbers:

The following should work:

`set nornu nonu`

Comment: Work, except is removed all line numbers. Need additional command:
`set number` to get plain line numbers back.
PS: No other solution provided here worked.